# Using php glob() to recursively get files in CS CART thumbnails directory

Tags: php, glob, cs-cart

I attempted to use glob() to recursively grab all the image files from the thumbnails directory of a CS CART installation but it failed to work. When I applied the same code to image directories, it worked.

Below is my PHP Script:

```
$img_folder = "../httpdocs/images/thumbnails/*/";   
$files = glob($img_folder . "*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($files);
echo "<br>";
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo "Uploading ";
    print_r($file);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

My directory setup for the 'images' folder:

```
..../images
       |
       +-- thumbnails
       |
       +-- detailed
       |
       +-- products
```

The above script works perfectly fine for 'detailed' and 'products' folder but not for 'thumbnails' folder.

How should I fix the problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
$img_folder = "../httpdocs/images/thumbnails/*/";
```

With

```
$img_folder = "../httpdocs/images/thumbnails/";
```

With

> /thumbnails/*/

You are looking for images in subdirectories of **thumbnails** folder, but not in the folder itself.